# Preserving Array Member Order in Postgres Query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I would like to know how to preserve/utilize the order of array elements when issuing a `select` query in Postgres. (In case it's relevant, the array is multidimensional.)

For example, given the following data:

```
 id |             points
----+---------------------------------
  1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}
  2 | {{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}}
```

I'd like to know how to write a query which finds rows whose `points`:

- contain the subarray `{{7, 11}, {99, 101}}`
- but *not* `{{99, 101},{7, 11}}`.

I've tried using various array operators (`@>`, `&&`), adding an index using the intarray module, etc. but have not found a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able to "unnest array by 1 dimention" and use the result set for `in`comarison, use [Pavel Stěhule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule) suggested [function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRD3DrqCa68NjHUcC8%3DyT1%3D7XvtYkxUMYFuuDuboixDcjw@mail.gmail.com):

```
t=# with c(i,p) as (values(1,'{{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}'::int[][]),(2,'{{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}}'))
, p as (select *,a,case when e = '{7, 11}' and lead(e) over (partition by i order by o) = '{99, 101}' and o = lead(o) over (partition by i order by o) -1 then true end from c, reduce_dim(p) with ordinality as a (e,o))
select * from p;
 i |                p                |    e     | o |       a        | case
---+---------------------------------+----------+---+----------------+------
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}   | {1,3}    | 1 | ("{1,3}",1)    |
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}   | {7,11}   | 2 | ("{7,11}",2)   | t
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}   | {99,101} | 3 | ("{99,101}",3) |
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}   | {0,1}    | 4 | ("{0,1}",4)    |
 2 | {{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}} | {99,101} | 1 | ("{99,101}",1) |
 2 | {{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}} | {7,11}   | 2 | ("{7,11}",2)   |
 2 | {{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}} | {0,1}    | 3 | ("{0,1}",3)    |
 2 | {{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}} | {77,22}  | 4 | ("{77,22}",4)  |
(8 rows)
```

now, that you see the logic, complete `where`:

```
t=# with c(i,p) as (values(1,'{{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}'::int[][]),(2,'{{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}}'))
, p as (select *,a,case when e = '{7, 11}' and lead(e) over (partition by i order by o) = '{99, 101}' and o = lead(o) over (partition by i order by o) -1 then true end from c, reduce_dim(p) with ordinality as a (e,o))
select i,p from p where "case";
 i |               p
---+-------------------------------
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}
(1 row)
```

not to mention that in case of sequential array pair, you can just cast it to text and use like operator:

```
t=# with c(i,p) as (values(1,'{{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}'::int[][]),(2,'{{99,101},{7,11},{0,1},{77,22}}'))
select * from c where p::text like '%{7,11},{99,101}%';
 i |               p
---+-------------------------------
 1 | {{1,3},{7,11},{99,101},{0,1}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks -- I will weigh these options and make one of them work. I'm surprised such a common use case (IMO) is impossible to accomplish using the provided array operators.